# (C++) How to declare a stl list as extern?

Tags: c++, list, stl, extern

I have:

```
std::list<Particle> particles;
std::list<Particle>::iterator particleit;
```

in my main.cpp. I need to declare both of these as extern in one of my class files, but my compiler gives me some error about a missing '>' when I try the straightforward way. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are you sure you're including `<list>` and your `Particle` header?

Comment: The exact code and the exact error message would definitely e better than an English description.

Comment: "I need to declare both of these as extern" -- I doubt that!

Answer (score 1):

```
extern std::list<Particle> particles;
```

If that doesn't work, then you have some other error.  Have you included `<list>` and is the definition of `Particle` visible where `particles` is declared?

Comment: Thanks. It compiles now. But I have another issue with the application freezing, now. I'll probably have that solved, though. Thanks again.

Comment: That can incur the initialization order fiasco… best practice is a `static` function local.

Comment: Right, the 'freeze' might come from an attempt to access the global object before it was initialized. Best practice is to avoid non-local objects at all, but if yon feel you must do it that way rather use a well designed singelton holder...